# Alias domain name on local network only

Tags: domain-name-system, router, port-forwarding

I run Owncloud 8 on a Raspberry Pi. It is hooked up to my router with IP `192.168.0.122`. I want to be able to access it from the internet using `mydomain.com`, so I signed up to a dynamic DNS service and set up a cronjob to update my IP. In the router, I set up port-forwarding for HTTP, HTTPS, and SSH. Everything is working like a charm when I access `mydomain.com` from outside my LAN. However, when accessing the domain from within my local network, I am presented with the router's web interface.

My layman's interpretation of what's going on is that the router realizes that the desired IP is itself so there's no need to route it outside, but then the port-forwarding doesn't trigger, so I end up at the router's web interface rather than the Pi.

One obvious workaround for me would be to add

```
192.168.0.122        mydomain.com
```

to the `/etc/hosts` files of the clients in the LAN. However, some of my devices are not bound to the LAN and I want to use them to access Owncloud also from the outside. Is there a way to route `mydomain.com` to `192.168.0.122` if and only if the device is on the local network. Or is this the wrong way to go about things entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please realize that mydomain.com (outside the LAN), and mydomain.com (LAN) have different IP addresses.

Therefore you need a separate DNS server to handle the addresses on the LAN so that you get a LAN and not a public WAN address.

Many firewalls provide this split-horizon DNS capability, but since you don't mention what you have for a FW ..... I cant guess.

Your interpretation should read "My Dynamic DNS is correctly setup, and external connections are just fine, proving that.  Internal LAN connection fail because the ONLY registered DNS for mydomain com is the dynmic DNS and that points to the public WAN IP, and not the untranslated private (192.x.x.x) IP I use internally"

And you cant add anything 192.168.x.x (or 10.0.0.0, or 172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x) to you dynamic DNS as these address ranges are officalyy "Unroutable" over the public internet.

Your LAN needs a DNS, your firewall needs a split-horizon DNS, or your computers need hosts files, to fix this.

Comment: BTW - getting it to work from the outside was the HARD part - you are ALMOST HOME NOW.   You LAN needs to resolve mydomain.com to a different address than the external dynamic DNS does and you will be finished.

Comment: I did not mention the FW because the router runs some custom firmware (it's what my ISP gave me). It doesn't have split-horizon DNS. I now set up dnsmasq on the Raspberry Pi and use it as the DNS server. Works nicely. Thanks, much appreciated.